# Apply AngularJS directive when div is visible

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have added a custom directive in Angular JS. I have added one page in which I have 4 div tag. These 4 div tag are not displayed at once, but they are getting displayed in tabs, so on click of particular tab respective div gets displayed.

But when the page loads all div tag are loaded so directive is called when page is loaded. But what I want to achieve is when the div tag gets visible (on click of tab) it should execute that directive.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks.

-- **Update - 1**

let me explain my problem with more details ..

I am displaying tabs using boot-strap data-toggle="tab", so when I select particular tab it displays that tab content.. but on click of tab bootstrap is showing / hiding tabs by applying css.

```
<a href="!#tab_1" data-toggle="tab">
<a href="!#tab_2" data-toggle="tab">
<a href="!#tab_3" data-toggle="tab">

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_1">
    ... some content
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_2">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in userList">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.contact}}</td>
            <a href="!#new_user_modal" data-toggle="modal">View</a> &nbsp;
            <a href="!#new_user_modal" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab_3">
    ... some content
</div>

<new-user-modal username="name"></new-user-modal>
```

so, now when i load page by default tab_1 is selected / active, but other tabs are already loaded but are hidden. Here `<new-user-modal>` is a custom directive, which points to a template using templateUrl ../../newUserTemplate.html, which has div with id new_user_modal.

So when I select tab_2, i see list of users, all user row will have View action, and when i click on View action, it displays pop-up using newUserTemplate.html template. I have implemented a custom directive to display all fields in form as read-only, so when user clicks on View action it should display all fields in read only mode.

template (../../newUserTemplate.html) div with id new_user_modal has this custom directive read-only added to it, so when i load page first time when by default tab_1 is selected that time its calling read-only custom directive.

But I want it to be called when action is clicked, so based on it i can open modal either in read-only or edit mode.

let me know if you need any other details..

--  **Update-2**

basically I have created two directives one is **new-user-modal** and other is **read-only**.

First directive is to load user details in a modal(popup) which as i explained is getting generated using data-toggler=modal. This directive **new-user-modal** has template which is a form with user related fields, so when user clicks on any user records, this modal will be displayed with user information..

**new-user-modal** directive is pointing to template file ../newUserTemplate.html, where i have all user fields. In this template i have added my another custom directive **read-only**, so if user clicks on view user action, it will open this modal in read only view means all form fields will be read only, and if user clicks on edit user action, same modal will open in edit mode.

But, as this modal is getting generated using bootstrap, this modal is already loaded when the page is loaded first time, but its hidden. So directive is getting called when page is loaded not when modal is shown ..

Comment: Make sure you're thinking about it in "the Angular way". Visibility (and probably tabs, too) should be controlled by the app.

Comment: my implementation of tab is using ul & li tags. on click of particular tab respective div is shown and others are hidden, but directive gets applied as the page loads, so i want that directive to be applied when div is visible.

Comment: Could you put all of your code? Your custom directives and anything related to this part of the logic. Is pretty hard to understand what do you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: please check update-2, i have added bit more information, read-only directive takes element on which directive is added and make all sub input fields read only.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ng-if` for directives and check if the current tab is open. `ng-if` recompiles the directive from scratch only when the value is true, or in your case

Something like this:

```
<tabs>
   <pane title="Tab1">
      <directive ng-if="tab1.active"> </directive>
   </pane>
   <pane title="Tab2">
      <directive ng-if="tab2.active"> </directive>
   </pane>
</tabs>
```

Is this something you want? There is also another way using `$compile` but it's not so correct.